# Pandas: How to subset (and sum) top N observations within subcategories?

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe such as this:

```
     year      month  passengers
0    1949    January         112
1    1949   February         118
2    1949      March         132
3    1949      April         129
4    1949        May         121
5    1949       June         135
.
.
.
137  1960       June         535
138  1960       July         622
139  1960     August         606
140  1960  September         508
141  1960    October         461
142  1960   November         390
143  1960   December         432
```

How can I subset (and do calculations on) the 3 months with the most passengers within each year?

The very same dataframe can be reproduced from a seaborn dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df
```

---

**Here's what I've tried:**

Following a suggestion in the comments from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472125/sort-pandas-dataframe-with-multiindex-according-to-column-value) I found out that I could subset the dataframe using `nlargest()` after reindexing the dataframe:

```
df = df.set_index(['year', 'month'])
df2 = df.groupby(level=0)['passengers'].nlargest(3)
df2
```

output:

```
year  year  month    
1949  1949  July         148
            August       148
            September    136
1950  1950  July         170
            August       170
```

But for some reason the `year index` is duplicated, and I'd still have to reindex, group the dataframe by year and sum the results. This is already starting to get messy, so is there no better way of doing this?

**Here's the whole thing for an easy copy-paste:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df = df.set_index(['year', 'month'])
df2 = df.groupby(level=0)['passengers'].nlargest(3)
```

**And here is the shape of the desired output:**

```
# Sum of top 3 months for each year (no index other than default pandas dataframe index)

    year    sum
0   1949    600 (the sum is made up)
1   1950    600
.
.
.
10  1960    600
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT: System info:**

Python  3.6.0

Pandas  0.19.2

Windows 7

Comment: That's funny: I copied your code, but I get a long exception chain, mostly stating `TypeError: nlargest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`, interwoven with `ValueError: Duplicated level name: "year", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.`. Pandas version 0.23.1, Seaborn version 0.8.1.

Comment: For me your solution return `ValueError`, maybe because another seaborn vesrion (in pandas 0.23.1)

Comment: I'm on pandas 0.19.2

Comment: @jezrael Just a plain `ValueError` is what you'll see when using Python 2. Python 3 has the chained tracebacks.

Comment: @9769953 - I use `python 3.6`

Comment: @jezrael `ValueError` is indeed the last error I get in the chain, but if you trace it back, you should see lots of "caused by" above that. Hence I quoted those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and `sum`:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df2 = df.groupby('year')['passengers'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).reset_index()
print (df2)
    year  passengers
0   1949         432
1   1950         498
2   1951         582
3   1952         690
4   1953         779
5   1954         859
6   1955        1026
7   1956        1192
8   1957        1354
9   1958        1431
10  1959        1579
11  1960        1763
```