# Pandas: How to group (and sum) by category and retain information from subcategory

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up question to [Pandas: How to subset (and sum) top N observations within subcategories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077487/pandas-how-to-subset-and-sum-top-n-observations-within-subcategories) There it was demonstrated how you could find the sum of the top 3 months for each year in this dataframe:

**Example dataframe**

```
    year      month   passengers
0    1949    January         112
1    1949   February         118
2    1949      March         132
3    1949      April         129
4    1949        May         121
5    1949       June         135
.
.
.
137  1960       June         535
138  1960       July         622
139  1960     August         606
140  1960  September         508
141  1960    October         461
142  1960   November         390
143  1960   December         432
```

So that you'd end up with this:

```
    year  passengers
0   1949         432
1   1950         498
2   1951         582
3   1952         690
4   1953         779
5   1954         859
6   1955        1026
7   1956        1192
8   1957        1354
9   1958        1431
10  1959        1579
11  1960         176
```

The number `432 for 1949` is the sum of `148+148+136 for the months July, August and September.`
My question now is this:

**Is it possible to do the same calculations, and at the same time keep the corresponding subcategories as a list in it's own column?**

**Desired output**

(I've only checked the actual sum for 1949. 1950 is made up):

```
        year  passengers  months
    0   1949         432  July, August, September 
    1   1950         498  August, September, December
    2   1951         582  .
    3   1952         690  .
    4   1953         779  .
    5   1954         859  .
    6   1955        1026  .
    7   1956        1192  .
    8   1957        1354  .
    9   1958        1431  .
    10  1959        1579  .
    11  1960         176  .
```

**Reproducible code and data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
print(df.head())

df2 = df.groupby('year')['passengers'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3).sum()).reset_index()
print(df2.head())
```

df:

```
   year     month  passengers
0  1949   January         112
1  1949  February         118
2  1949     March         132
3  1949     April         129
4  1949       May         121
```

df2:

```
   year  passengers
0  1949         432
1  1950         498
2  1951         582
3  1952         690
4  1953         779
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively - group, then apply using `pd.DataFrame.nlargest` instead of a custom function/lambda then regroup on the index and apply suitable `agg`s, eg:

```
new_df = (
    df.groupby('year').apply(pd.DataFrame.nlargest, 3, 'passengers')
    .groupby(level=0).agg({'passengers': 'sum', 'month': ', '.join})
    # optionally reset index
    # .reset_index()
)
```

That'll then give you:

```
      passengers                    month
year                                     
1949         432  July, August, September
1950         498  July, August, September
1951         582  July, August, September
1952         690       August, July, June
1953         779       August, July, June
1954         859       July, August, June
...
```

Seems that `year` as an index makes sense in the resultant frame, but apply a `.reset_index()` if not.

Answer (score 3):

Use  custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), idea is sorting first by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then call `head` for top values per groups:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.head(3)
    names = ['passengers','months']
    return pd.Series([x['passengers'].sum(), ', '.join(x['month'])], index=names)

df2 = df.sort_values('passengers', ascending=False).groupby('year').apply(f).reset_index()
print(df2.head())
   year  passengers                   months
0  1949         432  July, August, September
1  1950         498  July, August, September
2  1951         582  July, August, September
3  1952         690       August, July, June
4  1953         779       August, July, June
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
In [69]: df.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: 
           x.nlargest(3, 'passengers').agg(
              {'passengers': 'sum', 'month': lambda x: ', '.join(x.values)}
             )).reset_index()
Out[69]:
    year  passengers                    month
0   1949         432  July, August, September
1   1950         498  July, August, September
2   1951         582  July, August, September
3   1952         690       August, July, June
4   1953         779       August, July, June
5   1954         859       July, August, June
6   1955        1026       July, August, June
7   1956        1192       July, August, June
8   1957        1354       August, July, June
9   1958        1431       August, July, June
10  1959        1579       August, July, June
11  1960        1763       July, August, June
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using `nlargest`.

```
def largest(x, k):
    vals = x.nlargest(n=k, columns=['passengers'])
    return [vals['passengers'].sum(), vals['month'].tolist()]

g = df.groupby('year').apply(largest, k=3).reset_index()
joiner = pd.DataFrame(g[0].values.tolist(), columns=['passengers', 'months'])

res = g.drop(0, axis=1).join(joiner)

print(res)

   year  passengers               months
0  1949         382  [March, April, May]
```

I intentionally keep `months` as a list, you can convert to a comma separated string if you wish.